# Why inline input tag in html reacts to width and height properties?

Tags: html, css

[image: ![enter image description here]
Why here both input tags have width and height as I mentioned in css file? They both should ignore it as `inline` elements

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
<input class="reset" type="reset" value="Clear">
```

```
input
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, inputs are listed as being inline elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#list_of_inline_elements), but browsers have their own stylesheets called ***user agent stylesheets*** that set their own defaults when rendering HTML.

If you check chromium: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/refs/heads/main/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css#408, you'll see on line 419 that they're setting `input, textarea, select, button` to `display: inline-block;`.

Each browser has their own user agent stylesheet and if you check your browser developer tools, scroll through the css rules for an input. You'll eventually find the rule I referenced above.

Comment: As a counter-argument, you can create a snippet with this users code, add `display: inline` to their CSS block, and the inputs will still display with height and width applied...

Comment: @AlexanderNied I noticed that also. I was going to discuss that point but his question was why weren't they acting as inline.